# Profile page lists flags, but teams doesn't have flags

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

On my profile page it says I need 10 reputation for flagging, but I've been told that Stack Overflow Teams doesn't have flags.

[image]

Comment: Surprise ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEqQW.png :P

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow Teams have flags. You as a member in that team didn't have enough reputation to be able to flag in this case. Please note that each team has their own requirements of the flagging privilege.

For individual users, you need 15 reputation to flag (or vote), otherwise a lock icon will be displayed.

Comment: Actually what privileges you earn and when depends on how the particular team has set it... I am a member in both Sobotics team and Charcoal HQ and the reputation level is set differently. Also flagging is probably configurable to be disabled for a team.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj Rao. I have edited the answer.